# How to push values from .each() to one array in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
$(".section").each( function() {
    var x = $(this).attr('data-test');
    var y =[];
    y.push(x);
});
```

I will get 10 values for data-test, and I want to push them to the array 'y' to be like this:

```
['1','2','3','4','5','6'...'10']
```

How do I "split up" x into each of its values and push them to y?

EDIT:

HTML e.g:

```
<li class="section" data-test="15"></li>
<li class="section" data-test="6"></li>
<li class="section" data-test="78"></li>
```

and so on

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan x will contain 10 values as it's checking each 'data-test' for each section. At the moment when I console log y, I get 10 separate arrays with one value in each.

Answer (score 7):

Given your HTML sample you can use `map()` to create the array for you:

```js
var y = $(".section").map(function() {
    return $(this).data('test');
}).get();

// This is only for display purposes
$('div').text(JSON.stringify(y));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="section" data-test="15">15</li>
  <li class="section" data-test="6">6</li>
  <li class="section" data-test="78">78</li>
</ul>

<div></div>
```

Comment: There was another answer posted which I tried, and it worked, so I upvoted yours rather than selected as the correct answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Obligatory vanilla answer using ES6

```
var y = [];
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".section")).forEach(x => {
    y.push(x.getAttribute("data-test"))
});
```

The issue you're running into is you're resetting the array `y` upon each iteration, thus removing previous indexes.

`Array.from()` converts the NodeList returned from `querySelectorAll` into a nicer iterable, (you can also use `map` instead of `forEach`) then simply push the data attribute of `x` into the array

Answer (score 0):

`$.merge()` could be used to concatenate items to an array

```js
var y = [];

$(".section").each(function() {
  $.merge(y, [$(this).data("test")])
});

console.log(y)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="section" data-test="15"></li>
<li class="section" data-test="6"></li>
<li class="section" data-test="78"></li>
```